# Копирование файлов в C# вручную

Tags: c#, файлы

Доброго времени суток! Я начинающий программист, сейчас (для себя) пишу на C# простенький файловый менеджер. Дошел до реализации функции копирования файлов. Хочется написать свою функцию копирования (например, через *StreamReader* / *StreamWriter*). Хотел бы посоветоваться с более опытными программистами, стОит ли (с точки зрения скорости работы, эффективности и/или иных факторов) вообще этим заниматься? Или лучше воспользоваться методом *File.Copy*?

Дело в том, что было бы идеально реализовать *ProgressBar* копирования по объему, а не по кол-ву файлов, чтобы не возникало ситуаций, когда при копировании двух файлов - очень большого и очень маленького (например, iso-образ диска и readme к нему) полоска *ProgressBar* длительное время на нулю (завершено 0/2 файлов), и моментально на 100% - второй файл скопировался незаметно быстро.

Если стОит, то как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хотите отображать прогресс копирования, то использовать File.Copy однозначно не стоит. наглядные примеры копирования файлов в синхронном и асинхронном режиме с замерами скорости вы можете посмотреть здесь
[http://www.informit.com/](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=827)

Comment: Спасибо, реализовал с отображением в ProgressBar именно так, как хотел.